# How to access keys by it's index?

Tags: redis

I have a long key names in Redis, and would like to access them by their index. For example:

```
redis XXXX:6379[1]> KEYS *
1) "aaa"
2) "bbb"
3) "ccc"
4) "ddd"
```

And what I would like to do is something like:

```
redis XXXX:6379[1]> GET '1'
```

or

```
redis XXXX:6379[1]> GET KEYS[1]
```

To retrieve information about selected key.

Comment: This will be painfully slow compared to accessing an object by the key. You should find a way to use the key if at all possible. `KEYS` is expensive and the index of a key isn't going to stay the same if you are adding/removing keys a lot. You should think about having a LIST that contains your keys in an order if you need that, then look up the key in the LIST by index.

Answer (score 0):

Using redis-cli on ubuntu I am able to do following case:

1. search for keys and sort them

   prompt>redis-cli keys a*|sort
   ak
   aka
   asdf
2. To get first key

   > redis-cli keys a*|sort|head -n 1
3. Top 2 keys

   > redis-cli keys a*|sort|head -n 2
4. get second element

   > redis-cli keys a*|sort|head -n 2 |tail -1

This solution could be used in scripts.